# How to find words with two vowels

Tags: python, regex

How to find words with two vowels in the middle in a string using python regular expression

this is my code :

```
s= "reading a book is great"

print(re.findall(r'\b(\w+[aeiyou]+w)\b',s))
```

expected output: `[book]`

my output: `[book],[grea]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `+` in your regex with `{2}`, because `+` repeats the previous token one or more times where `{2}` repeats the previous token exactly the 2 times.

```
print(re.findall(r'\b\w[aeiou]{2}\w\b',s))
```

For both upper and lowercase vowels.

```
print(re.findall(r'\b\w[aeiouAEIOU]{2}\w\b',s))
```

You could use `[A-Za-z]` instead of `\w`, if you don't want a digit or `_` exists before or after the vowels. Because `\w` also matches `_` and digits.

```
print(re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z][aeiouAEIOU]{2}[A-Za-z]\b',s))
```

Add case-insensitive modifier `(?i)` or `re.IGNORECASE` to do a case-insensitive match.

```
print(re.findall(r'(?i)\b[a-z][aeiou]{2}[a-z]\b',s))
```

Comment: A real [tag:regex] beast :D

Comment: That's why they created case-insensitive modifiers, so you can simplify patterns =)