# Regex (Python) - Match words with two or more distinct vowels

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to match words in a string that contain two or more distinct vowels.  The question can be restricted to lowercase.

```
string = 'pool pound polio papa pick pair'
```

Expected result:

```
pound, polio, pair
```

`pool` and `papa` would fail because they contain only one distinct vowel. However, `polio` is fine, because even though it contains two `o`s, it contains two distinct vowels (`i` and `o`).  `mississippi` would fail, but `albuquerque` would pass).

Thought process: Using a lookaround, perhaps five times (ignore uppercase), wrapped in a parenthesis, with a `{2}` afterward.  Something like:

```
re.findall(r'\w*((?=a{1})|(?=e{1})|(?=i{1})|(?=o{1})|(?=u{1})){2}\w*', string)
```

However, this matches on all six words.

I killed the `{1}`s, which makes it prettier (the `{1}`s seem to be unnecessary), but it still returns all six:

```
re.findall(r'\w*((?=a)|(?=e)|(?=i)|(?=o)|(?=u))\w*', string)
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.  I checked other queries, including ["How to find words with two vowels"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689858/how-to-find-words-with-two-vowels), but none seemed close enough.  Also, I'm looking for pure RegEx.

Comment: "The {1}s seem unnecessary" suggests you are not quite aware what it does. The parentheses make things unclear but I don't think you can repeat a lookahead two times – if the syntax allows it (and apparently it does, because else you'd get an error), then it tests the same lookahead *twice*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need 5 separate lookaheads, that's complete overkill. Just capture the first vowel in a [capture group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping), and then use a [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions) to assert that it's different from the second vowel:

```
[a-z]*([aeiou])[a-z]*(?!\1)[aeiou][a-z]*
```

[See the online demo.](https://regex101.com/r/K2Yppn/1)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you.  It would seem "capturing groups" and that funky little "\1" will be my next focus of study.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Your `\w*((?=a)|(?=e)|(?=i)|(?=o)|(?=u))\w*` regex matches all words that have at least 1 any vowel. `\w*` matches 0+ word chars, so the first pattern grabs the whole chunk of letters, digits and underscores. Then, backtracking begins, the regex engine tries to find a location that is followed with either `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`. Once it finds that location, the previously grabbed word chars are again grabbed and consumed with the trailing `\w*`.

To match whole words with at least 2 different vowels, you may use

```
\b(?=\w*([aeiou])\w*(?!\1)[aeiou])\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gWrubw/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=\w*([aeiou])\w*(?!\1)[aeiou])` - a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that, immediately to the left of the current location, requires

  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars
  - `([aeiou])` - [**Capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 (its value is referenced to with [`\1` **backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) later in the pattern): any vowel
  - `\w*` - 0+ word chars
  - `(?!\1)[aeiou]` - any vowel from the `[aeiou]` set that is not equal to the vowel stored in Group 1 (due to the negative lookahead `(?!\1)` that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, the [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) pattern match is found)
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars.

Answer (score 0):

Match words in a string that contain at least two distinct vowels in the least amount of characters (to my knowledge): `\w*([aeiou])\w*(?!\1)[aeiou]\w*`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uRgVVa/1

Explanation:

- `\w*`: matches 0 or more word characters. You don't need to start with a word boundary (`\b`) because `\w` does not include spaces, so using `\b` would be redundant.
- `([aeiou])`: `[aeiou]` matches any one vowel. It is in parenthesis so we can reference what vowel was matched later. Whatever is inside these first parenthesis is group 1.
- `\w*`: matches 0 or more word characters.
- `(?!\1)`: says the following regex cannot be the same as the character selected in group 1. For example, if the vowel matched in group 1 was `a`, the following regex cannot be `a`. This is called by `\1`, which references what character was chosen in group 1 (e.g. if `a` matched group 1, `\1` references `a`). `?!` is a negative lookahead that says the following regex outside the parenthesis cannot match what follows `?!`.
- `\w*`: matches 0 or more word characters.